# Cannot find RAW image plugin for GIMP under Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, gimp

I'm looking for a way to edit RAW image files with Gimp on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Various web pages recommend UFRAW or gimp-dcraw, but neither of these seem to be available for 22.04 LTS.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try RawTherapee? It is available in the Ubuntu 22.04 repository (`rawtherapee`).

Comment: No, I haven’t tried RawTherapee. I’ll try it. Thank you.